# Search in front of background image redirects to home page on click

Tags: php, html, css

I have a header image where there is also a search field.

However, when I click on the search input I get redirected to home page because my search is inside the  tag.

How can I prevent this, when I want to make a search inside the header which has a background image.

I want the search feature NOT to go back to homepage, yet I want the background image to go back to homepage.

Here is my code:

```
<header>
    <h1>
        <a href="/">
            <span class="texte-cache">Sel gras</span>
            <section class="section-recherche">
                <?php
                // define variables and set to empty values
                $rechercheErr = "";
                $recherche  = "";
                $rechercheValid = false;
                ?>

                <form method="get" action="../pages/recherche.php">
                    <div class="recherche">
                        <input type="search" name="recherche" id="recherche" placeholder="Rechercher..." value="<?php echo $recherche; ?>" />
                        <span class="error"> <?php echo $rechercheErr; ?></span>
                        <button title="Rechercher" class="button-recherche" id="buttonRecherche" name="submit"><i class="material-icons-white">search</i></button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </section>
        </a>
    </h1>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/styles.css" media="all" />
</header>
```

If there is way I can change my html so visual I can stil have this I would be very happy (see image)

[image: Image of what I want to have]

Any help would be very appreciated. Also I am not allowed to use jquery, javascript.....

Comment: Can you set any #hash from url then get hash based apply

Comment: @vadivela I dont understand what you mean?

Comment: Can you use query parameter to redirected url

Comment: If it is in php yes

Comment: Why don't you remove your form from `<a>` element... It is also not semantic to have a `<form>` inside a `<a>` element, see docs: [HTML Semantics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Semantics)

Comment: Change that to `<a href="javascript:void(0)">`. Does that help?

Comment: @Gosi no because when I click on the image I want to go back to home page.

Comment: @caiovisk If I have the same thing visualy I would be fine with changing the html but I dont know how to change so I can have the same thing visualy

Comment: @JuniorCortenbach Sorry but I am so confused, you mentioned you want to prevent it from going to your homepage in your question but now you also mention that it should go back. Can you please re-edit your question.

Comment: @JuniorCortenbach oh wait a minute, you want the search feature NOT to go back to homepage, yet you want that background image to go back to homepage. Is that it?

Comment: Yes @Gosi you are correct I did not know that my question was unclear thank you for the information I will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out here is my new html

```
<header>
    <h1>
        <a href="/">
            <span class="texte-cache">Sel gras</span>
        </a>


     <section class="section-recherche">
                <?php
                // define variables and set to empty values
                $rechercheErr = "";
                $recherche  = "";
                $rechercheValid = false;
                ?>

                <form method="get" action="../pages/recherche.php">
                    <div class="recherche">
                        <input type="search" name="recherche" id="recherche" placeholder="Rechercher..." value="<?php echo $recherche; ?>" />
                        <span class="error"> <?php echo $rechercheErr; ?></span>
                        <button title="Rechercher" class="button-recherche" id="buttonRecherche" name="submit"><i class="material-icons-white">search</i></button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </section>

    </h1>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/styles.css" media="all" />


</header>
```

And here is what I did in the css I gave search form a absolute position.

```
.section-recherche{
  position: absolute;
  top: 220px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  width: 80%;
}
```